# Not enough Cloud space to export RB1 songs for RB4, what now?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, rock-band, rock-band-4

I've read 10 different explanations on how to get my Rock Band 1 songs from my Xbox 360 to Rock Band 4 on my Xbox One, but they all seem to be missing some really important step that I don't understand.

On RB1, I can export my songs (I did so awhile back to get them into RB2) to local disk, but I'm not sure how that helps me get them to my Xbox One. I've tried exporting them to Cloud Saved Games, but my RB1 export is 1.52GB and I've only got 0.5 GB of Cloud space.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you export them to an external HDD? That way you could port them from the 360 to the One.

Comment: How do I import them to my Xbox One from the external HDD?

Comment: I don't have the games so I am not sure. I presume the game would have an import function and you would merely point to where the data is located. However, it looks like you were able to get a hold of the information you needed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the RB1 disc songs aren't exportable yet, but Harmonix says they are working on that for early next year (2016).

https://twitter.com/RockBand/status/681558265101205505

[image]